# Shell- not able to produce log output of script

Tags: shell, ksh

I am trying to run following command

```
ssh xxx@99.99.99.99 ". ./.profile; myscript  2&1 >> /tmp/2244455.log"
```

But it comes up with following error

```
sh: 1: execute permission denied
```

When i run `myscript  2&1 >> /tmp/2244455.log` on my remote server it works perfectly.

Also when i run `ssh xxx@99.99.99.99 ". ./.profile; myscript` it works perfectly.

Please can yo help me with this issue

myscript is not owned by xxx, permissions are

`ls -ltrh myscript
-rwxr-xr-x   1 yyy      other        11K May 18 15:04 myscript`

Comment: Do you (or the user who run the script) have write permissions on /tmp/2244455.log or /tmp ? There is acl config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2&1 syntax is wrong; if you want to redirect stderr to stdout, you need to:

```
2>&1
```

You also have quotes that are not nested properly; the backtick `` is overlapped with the double quotes.  EDIT:  I see you've edited the question, but there's now an unpaired backtick at the beginning of your command

So, I'm guessing what you're after with the quotes, but your whole command might be:

```
ssh xxx@99.99.99.99 ". ./.profile; myscript  2>&1 >> /tmp/2244455.log"
```

This would create /tmp/2244455.log on the remote 99.99.99.99 machine.

Answer (score 1):

Putting backpacks around the `ssh` command will cause your local shell to attempt to run its output as a new command line. Get rid of those, if that's not just a typo from formatting your question.

The real problem is that you're missing the `>` on the redirect. `2>&1`, not `2&1`. The `>`less version just adds 2 as an argument to the command and then attempts to run that command in the background while running a command named `1` in the foreground.